# Can I add a table through PGF \nextgroupplot functionality?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I have made a minimal working example which shows how far I am right now:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% Default preamble
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
% Custom preamble from global variable:
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size={2 by 2}}, height={4cm}, width={4cm}]
    \nextgroupplot[title={1}]
    \addplot+
        coordinates {
            (0,0)
            (1,1)
            (2,2)
        }
        ;
        
    \nextgroupplot[title={2}]
%                        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
%                       col sep=&,  % specify the column separation character
%                       row sep=\\, % specify the row separation character
%                       columns/E/.style={string type} % specify the type of data in the designated column
%                        ]{
%                           A & B & C & D & E \\
%                           1 & 10 & 0.1 & 1000 & 2011-01-01 \\
%                           2 & 20 & 0.2 & 2000 & 2012-02-02 \\
%                           3 & 30 & 0.3 & 3000 & 2013-03-03 \\
%                           4 & 40 & 0.4 & 4000 & 2014-04-04 \\
%                           5 & 50 & 0.5 & 5000 & 2015-05-05 \\
%                        }


    \nextgroupplot[title={3}]
    \addplot+
        coordinates {
            (0,2)
            (1,1)
            (2,1)
        }
        ;
    \nextgroupplot[title={4}]
    \addplot+
        coordinates {
            (0,2)
            (1,1)
            (1,0)
        }
        ;
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Running this code produces the following figure:

[image]

Instead of the empty figure to the top right, ("2"), I want to insert a table. This table has already been defined in my code, but commented (with `%`) - if I uncomment and run my LaTeX code again the result becomes:

[image]

Would anyone know how to stay in this workflow with `\nextgroupplot`, and be able to resolve this problem, such that I can insert a table instead of a figure?

Kind regards

Comment: Does the table datas correspond  to the plots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the empty axis with

```
\nextgroupplot[hide axis]
```

and then add the table in a node after `\end{groupplot}`. The axes are named `group cNrM`, where `N` and `M` are column and row numbers respectively, so you can use for example

```
\node [below right, xshift=-5mm] at (group c2r1.north west) { <table code> };
```

Whether you're using `\pgfplotstabletypeset` or a `tabular` directly doesn't matter, but you can't have a `table` environment in the node.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
% Default preamble
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\usepgfplotslibrary{smithchart}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
% Custom preamble from global variable:
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size={2 by 2}}, height={4cm}, width={4cm}]
    \nextgroupplot[title={1}]
    \addplot+
        coordinates {
            (0,0)
            (1,1)
            (2,2)
        }
        ;
        
    \nextgroupplot[hide axis]
    

    \nextgroupplot[title={3}]
    \addplot+
        coordinates {
            (0,2)
            (1,1)
            (2,1)
        }
        ;
    \nextgroupplot[title={4}]
    \addplot+
        coordinates {
            (0,2)
            (1,1)
            (1,0)
        }
        ;
\end{groupplot}

    \node [below right, xshift=-5mm] at (group c2r1.north west) {
                        \pgfplotstabletypeset[
                       col sep=&,  % specify the column separation character
                       row sep=\\, % specify the row separation character
                       columns/E/.style={string type} % specify the type of data in the designated column
                        ]{
                           A & B & C & D & E \\
                           1 & 10 & 0.1 & 1000 & 2011-01-01 \\
                           2 & 20 & 0.2 & 2000 & 2012-02-02 \\
                           3 & 30 & 0.3 & 3000 & 2013-03-03 \\
                           4 & 40 & 0.4 & 4000 & 2014-04-04 \\
                           5 & 50 & 0.5 & 5000 & 2015-05-05 \\
                        }};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is what I wanted, in a much more robust way in what I figured out at the end.

Could you show me how I would go about adding a table like this using the "normal" table enviroment in LaTex?

For an example one generated by https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables# 

When I try I get an error about a missing item

Kind regards

Comment: @CuriosLatex You can't add a `table` environment in that context, but just remove/comment `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}`. Do you want a caption?

Comment: Oh you are right, my bad. I got it to work by removing the lines you mentioned and only keeping the tabular. Afterwards I discovered I had forgot to escape a $ correctly. 

I have updated my question with the final result for my MWE, thanks once again!

Comment: @CuriosLatex You actually tried editing my answer, but anyways, I'll just add a note saying that if you have a `tabular` instead of a `\pgfplotstabletypeset` that works the same.

Comment: Sorry I suppose I am bit tired. I spent a good few hours trying to figure this out, so I am pretty happy that you took time to write me a detailed answer

Once again thanks!

Comment: @CuriosLatex No problem, and you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a table next to a group of plots has something to do with these plots.

In this version the plots are as big as the table.

To place the plots and the table by a loop (where the table was setted to the number 0)

```
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \n in {1,0,2,3}{%%
\ifnum\n=0 \nextgroupplot[title=The Table,hide axis]
                   \addplot[draw=none]{x}; % so no warnings
\else
\edef\tmp{
   \noexpand\nextgroupplot[title=Title\n, ylabel=y\n, xlabel=x]
   \noexpand\addplot+[black, mark options={color\n}, thick] table[x=X, y=Y\n]{\noexpand\data};
              }\tmp     
\fi}%%
```

has the advantage, that you can control where the table (plots) shall appear: You can choose `{1,0,2,3}` or `{1,2,3,0}` or...

[image]

With `\def\ShowHelps{0}% 1 "yes"   0 "no"`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
 \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\def\ShowHelps{1}% 1 "yes"   0 "no"

\pgfplotstableread[]{
X       Y1     Y2    Y3       Date 
1      10     0.1   100      2011-01-01     
2      20     0.2   200      2012-02-02     
3      30     0.3   300      2013-03-03     
4      40     0.4   400      2014-04-04     
5      50     0.5   500      2015-05-05     
}\data

\foreach \n/\mycolor in {1/red, 2/blue!66, 3/purple}{
\xglobal\colorlet{color\n}{\mycolor}          }

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,3}{
\pgfplotstableset{every col no #1/.style={
column type/.add={>{\columncolor{color#1}}}{}       }, }
}

\newsavebox{\mytable}
\sbox{\mytable}{%
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
columns/Date/.style={string type} 
]{\data}}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\tablewidth{width("\usebox{\mytable}")}
%\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\tableheight{height("\usebox{\mytable}")}% not good
\newlength{\tabheight}
\settototalheight{\tabheight}{\usebox{\mytable}} % good
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\tableheight{\the\tabheight}


\ifnum\ShowHelps=1 
\tikzset{Help/.style={draw=#1,  
nodes={scale=0.6, fill=yellow, draw=#1, text=black, font=\tiny, midway, above, align=left,} },
Help/.default=red, 
}\else
\tikzset{Help/.style={opacity=0, overlay},
}\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
group size={2 by 2},
horizontal sep=44pt, vertical sep=45pt,
}, 
scale only axis,    % 1/2  
width=\tablewidth, height=\tableheight, % 2/2
]
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \n in {1,0,2,3}{%%
\ifnum\n=0 \nextgroupplot[title=The Table,hide axis]
                   \addplot[draw=none]{x}; % so no warnings
\else
\edef\tmp{
   \noexpand\nextgroupplot[title=Title\n, ylabel=y\n, xlabel=x]
   \noexpand\addplot+[black, mark options={color\n}, thick] table[x=X, y=Y\n]{\noexpand\data};
              }\tmp     
\fi}%%

% Help 1/2
\xdef\verticalsep{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/group/vertical sep}}
\xdef\horizontalsep{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/group/horizontal sep}}
\end{groupplot}
% Help 2/2
\node[draw=gray, anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt] (X) at (group c2r1.north west) {\usebox{\mytable}};
\draw[Help, -|] (X.north west) -- +(\tablewidth,0) node[Help, near start]{\tablewidth \\ tablewidth}; 
\draw[Help, -|] (X.north west) -- +(0,-\tableheight) node[Help, rotate=90]{\tableheight \\ tableheight}; 
\draw[Help,-|] (group c2r1.south west) -- +(0,-\verticalsep) node[Help, rotate=90]{\verticalsep \\ vertical sep}; 
\draw[Help,-|] (group c2r1.south west) -- +(-\horizontalsep,0)  node[Help]{\horizontalsep \\ horizontal sep};  
\draw[Help,dashed] (group c2r1.north west) -- +(-\tablewidth-\horizontalsep,0); 
\draw[Help,dashed] (group c2r1.south west) -- +(-\tablewidth-\horizontalsep,0); 
\draw[Help,dashed] (group c2r2.south west) -- +(0,\tableheight) ; 
\draw[Help,dashed] (group c2r2.south east) -- +(0,2*\tableheight+\verticalsep) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```